# Play framework + Greenscript + 'url' CSS rules = wrong path

Tags: playframework, greenscript

When using the configuration option `greenscript.minimize=true` with [Greenscript](http://www.playframework.org/modules/greenscript-1.2.5/home), all CSS url resources becomes wrong. For example, with jQuery UI,

```
.ui-widget-content { border: 1px solid #dddddd; background: #eeeeee url(images/ui-bg_highlight-soft_100_eeeeee_1x100.png) 50% top repeat-x; color: #333333; }
```

will look for `images/ui-bg_highlight-soft_100_eeeeee_1x100.png` under the `gs` folder, and will not find it, because the resources are under `styles/themes/lightness` (for example).

One obvious solution would be to *manually* replace all relative paths to absolute paths. But is there another (better) solution (not having to modify the original CSS files)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a problem with current greenscript implementation. The fix should be released in later versions.

For your specific case, say jquery-ui, I recommend you to use CDN delivered css to avoid this issue. E.g. #{greenscript.css 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css' /}

Comment: Fixed in v1.2.6c : https://github.com/greenlaw110/greenscript/issues/18#issuecomment-2035619